# Ruby on Rails with jquery load and sending data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, load

I am wondering how I can send data. I have the following code

```
$( "#dialog" ).load('/events/relates ' + '#eventconfirm', { data: 'Hello World' }).dialog('open');
```

But it doesn't work. What I want is to load `event/relates` and only get the selection `#eventconfirm`, which works, but I would like to add data so the controller can read the `params[:data]` and act upon it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to append the url and try calling the plugin in the `.load` callback like

```
$("#dialog").dialog();//first initailize the plugin
//then load the content 
$( "#dialog" ).load('/events/relates#eventconfirm', { data: 'Hello World' },function(data){
 $(this).dialog('open');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JwpzT/)

Comment: I just implement ur solution, however i just see loading, it doesn't fetch it does the server has to have something special?

Comment: make sure your url is correct, have you checked the firebug for any errors?

Comment: i have included a demo in the answer

Comment: yeah thanks, i have look on chrome didn't look with in firefox, i also know that if i remove the data section it sends me the html i am looking for

Comment: are you receiving the data at the server or just loading a static html page? if its a static page then you dont need the data part just remove it altogether

Comment: well its a static page, like Article.all but i want to send parameters that can refine the search a bit more, i am getting though a 404 error

Comment: try putting the url directly into the browser address bar so to make sure the resource you are trying to load resides at the said location

Comment: yeah, the url does exist, i must admit though the load and .dialog is occuring during onclick

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```
$('.div').load("/test/okay?test=1");

where test=1 is params
```